# how to declare pointer to volatile struct

Tags: c

Let's say I have the following definitions :

```
/* Generic structure of entire SFR area for each UART module */
typedef struct tagUART {
        unsigned int uxmode;
        unsigned int uxsta;
        unsigned int uxtxreg;
        unsigned int uxrxreg;
        unsigned int uxbrg;
} UART, *PUART;



/* SFR blocks for each UART module */
extern volatile UART UART1 __attribute__((__sfr__));
extern volatile UART UART2 __attribute__((__sfr__));
```

Now if I acces the register through UART1, everything is fine, but what if I us a pointer to the structure, how should I declare it to specify the whole aera pointed to is volatile ?

```
volatile UART * hw = &UART1;
```

Is that ok ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you declare

```
extern volatile UART UART1;
```

Then any pointer derived from that variable will be of type `volatile UART *` and as a matter of fact your compiler should issue a warning if you try to assign it to any other type of variable.

If you wish `UART` to always be `volatile` then you can typedef it as such

```
typedef volatile struct {...} tagUART UART;
```

Or as unwind said to declare specific fields as volatile

```
typedef struct tagUART {
        volatile unsigned int uxmode;
        unsigned int uxsta;
        volatile unsigned int uxtxreg;
        unsigned int uxrxreg;
        unsigned int uxbrg;
} UART, *PUART;
```

The inline use of `volatile` i.e.

```
while (*(volatile int *)&a) ;
```

is discouraged and should only be used for variables that are normally not volatile, but have to be in this context.

Another way is to have a `union` where accessing one version is volatile another is not:

```
union {
    volatile UART volatile_version;
    UART normal;
};
```

Comment: Since there never exists a case where you wouldn't want UART registers to be volatile, using the typedef volatile on the whole struct is the correct way.

Comment: Are you sure about your first point, ie UART * hw = &UART1 is sufficient, and the volatile will be transfered to the pointer ?

Comment: @shodanex taking the address of a `volatile` variable will return a pointer to `volatile`, but if you intent to save that address in another variable then it also needs to carry `volatile`. `&UART1` has type `volatile UART *`, but `UART * hw = &UART1` will invoke a typecast into a pointer to non-volatile - here you need to write `volatile UART * hw = &UART1`.

Answer (score 1):

I think that's the wrong way; what if somebody (=you three months later) uses a pointer to `USART` but forget about the `volatile` part?

The proper way is to declare each field as being `volatile`. It's a bit messy, but better since it captures more of what you're trying to model right there in the code.

You often see a macro such as `__IO` being used for fields of structures that model hardware registers, and it typically includes `volatile` in its expansion.

Comment: I agree, but since it is a "vendor provided" include, I would like to avoid modifying it. Of course I could redeclare the whole thing...